# Auditing files in Windows Server 2012 R2 is too basic?

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, network-share

I have a TS on which I want to monitor who creates files (and when) inside a shared folder.

I have noticed that this is attainable using Auditing but I have noticed that the monitor options are restricted?

This is based on the Event ID:

4660- delete file (the only one that's obvious)

I'm trying to test around to see who creates a file and have noticed that these do not have seperate ID's.

What methods can I use to monitor the shared directories?